# Does anyone know of published data on Mach interactions with various asymmetrical toroids?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, resource-recommendations, geometry, shock-waves

I was looking for any lab conducted tests, or computer models of Mach reflections off of different toroids. How would shock waves propagate through asymmetrical 180° ring toroids, what kind of pressure flows would be generated?

I have a lot of different questions about what could happen so I will just ask for resources. I got curious about this because of the toroidal propellers that are currently hitting the market.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was just given a link to a certain nasa dataset that includes all the information I was looking for.

If anyone in the future is as curious about this as I am I shall leave it right here for them:

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20030002240/downloads/20030002240.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwj59seMrbqDAxXxAzQIHRQcCOkQFnoECBAQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1b7lkefS5K7vbPBGLc2S-a